# Posting on behalf of user set privacy to "Only you" like it to be "Everyone" or "Friends"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

I'm trying to post to wall on behalf of a user (user access token) via the Graph API. The post is successful and I get a api ID for the post. But I can't view it as the posting user.

On my friends wall the post shows up but it are marked in "privacy" settings as "Only you".

Are you able to set some other privacy setting like "Everyone" or "Friends" when using the graph api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sure has with facebook privacy settings of personal profile, and can't be set via an API request/post.

The `privacy` parameter of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ can't change this when posting to other than (access token) owners wall.

> Note: This privacy setting only applies to posts to the current or
>   specified user's own Wall. Facebook ignores this setting for targeted
>   Wall posts (when the user is writing on the Wall of a friend, Page,
>   event, group connected to the user). Consistent with behavior on
>   Facebook, all targeted posts are viewable by anyone who can see the
>   target's Wall.